# social-auth gives "wrong" facebook id

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-opengraph, django-socialauth, facebook-chat

I use django social-auth for facebook login and need to get facebook user id for using in facebook chat xmpp. Playing it manually, i knew that my id is 10000xxxxxxxxxxxxx but then noticed that social-auth holds another id: 77061xxxxxxxxx4

```
request.user.social_auth.get(provider='facebook').uid
```

Both of them work and redirect to my fb account when in browser but I can't use for facebook chat xmpp the one which social-auth has. Please advice.

Comment: FYI: Facebook’s chat API is going to be retired with API v1 on April 30th, 2015.

Comment: I am not using Chat API. XMPP

Comment: Same thing … see at the very bottom of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog/, _“The Chat/XMPP service and API, located at chat.facebook.com, will not be available once 1.0 is deprecated.”_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a wrong ID, since v2.0 you don´t get the global ID anymore but only a so called "App Scoped ID". It is unique in one App and will stay the same, but you will get another one in another App.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog